# Golang: how can I call win32 API without cgo?

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, go

I'm trying to call `GetUserNameEx` from `secur32.dll` like this:

```
dll, err := syscall.LoadDLL("secur32.dll")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer dll.Release()

GetUserNameEx, err := dll.FindProc("GetUserNameExW")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
arr := make([]uint8, 256)
var size uint
GetUserNameEx.Call(3, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&arr[0])), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&size)))
fmt.Println(arr)
fmt.Println(size)
```

This code compiles fine, but `GetUserNameEx.Call()` will fail. I don't know why I cannot get `UserName`. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`size` is an in-out parameter. When you make the call, you have to set it to the size of the buffer (`arr`). Also its type is `PULONG`, so in Go use `uint32`. Windows [`PULONG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx#PULONG) type is a pointer to a [`ULONG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx#ULONG) (which has range `0..4294967295`). See [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435(v=vs.85).aspx).

Also `Call()` returns 3 values:

```
func (p *Proc) Call(a ...uintptr) (r1, r2 uintptr, lastErr error)
```

Store the returned `lastErr` and print it. Would you have done so, you would find the error earlier:

```
_, _, lastErr := GetUserNameEx.Call(
    3, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&arr[0])), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&size)))

fmt.Println(lastErr)
```

Prints:

```
More data is available.
```

This means more data is available than what fits into the buffer you pass  - *or rather* - by the size you indicated with the in-out parameter `size` (you passed `0` as the `size`).

Working code (note the division by 2 due to unicode and minus 1 for the terminating `'\0'` byte / character for the size calculation):

```
arr := make([]uint8, 256)
var size uint32 = uint32(len(arr)) / 2 - 1
_, _, lastErr := GetUserNameEx.Call(
    3, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&arr[0])), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&size)))

fmt.Println(lastErr)
fmt.Println(string(arr))
fmt.Println(arr)
fmt.Println(size)
```

In this case `lastErr` will be:

```
The operation completed successfully.
```

To properly handle error:

> The returned error is always non-`nil`, constructed from the result of `GetLastError`. Callers must inspect the primary return value to decide whether an error occurred (according to the semantics of the specific function being called) before consulting the error. The error will be guaranteed to contain `syscall.Errno`.

Example:

```
r1, _, lastErr := GetUserNameEx.Call(
    3, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&arr[0])), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&size)))

if r1 == 0 {
    fmt.Println("ERROR:", lastErr.Error())
    return
}
// No error, proceed to print/use arr
```

Comment: >size is an in-out parameter  
omg I don't know that. Thanks icza, now my code working fine.

Comment: @エヌガミ Please see edited code, added error handling which greatly helps detecting errors.