# Load Windows DLLs in Go?

Tags: go

I need to use Windows DLLs in my applications, specificaly kernel32.dll.
I only find this: [WindowsDLL](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsDLLs)

But that "guide" is not so intiuitive.

For example, in Python you use ctypes. ej: `ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTextAtribute(handle, color)`

How I can made the same thing but in Golang?

Anyone can give some examples of that I want?

Comment: Check out these questions for some guidance: [Golang: how can I call win32 API without cgo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709033/golang-how-can-i-call-win32-api-without-cgo/33709631#33709631), and [Implement a global hotkey in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646794/implement-a-global-hotkey-in-golang/38954281#38954281)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the link you have is a good reference.
All you need now is choose one of the implementations proposed.

You can find the documentation for `kernel32.SetConsoleTextAtribute` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute

The exposed API is defined as:

```
BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleTextAttribute(
  _In_ HANDLE hConsoleOutput,
  _In_ WORD   wAttributes
);
```

Example for the second option (using `syscall.NewProc`):

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

const (
    // defined base colors
    ForegroundBlue      uint = 1
    ForegroundGreen     uint = 2
    ForegroundRed       uint = 4
    ForegroundIntensity uint = 8
    BackgroundBlue      uint = 16
    BackgroundGreen     uint = 32
    BackgroundRed       uint = 64
    BackgroundIntensity uint = 128

    // colors can also be mixed
    ForegroundGrey = ForegroundBlue | ForegroundGreen | ForegroundRed
    ForegroundWhite = ForegroundBlue | ForegroundGreen | ForegroundRed | ForegroundIntensity
)

func main() {
    kernel32 := syscall.NewLazyDLL("kernel32.dll")
    setConsoleTextAttribute := kernel32.NewProc("SetConsoleTextAttribute")
    stdOutHandle := os.Stdout.Fd()

    attributes := ForegroundWhite | BackgroundRed
    ret, _, err := setConsoleTextAttribute.Call(stdOutHandle, uintptr(attributes))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // calling kernel32.SetConsoleTextAttribute failed
    }

    if ret == 0 {
        print("Could not set the desired attributes")
        // TODO: call GetLastError to get more information
    }

    print("OK")
}
```